# Can't understand python code to make server

Tags: python, sockets, server

```
from socket import *
serverPort=15000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print 'the web server is up on port:',serverPort

while True:

 print 'Ready to serve...'
 connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

 try:

    message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    print message,'::',message.split()[0],':',message.split()[1]
    filename = message.split()[1]
    print filename,'||',filename[1:]
    f = open(filename[1:])
    outputdata = f.read()
    print outputdata
    connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n')
    connectionSocket.send(outputdata)

    for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
        connectionSocket.close()

 except IOError:
    connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n')
    connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n\n')
```

I cant seem to understand what

> for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
>           connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
>           connectionSocket.close()

is used for. When I place connectionSocket.close() outside the for loop, The server loads up the page but allows multiple hosts to connect to the server.
(Otherwise,Server stops when one host connects.)

Also, why are we using **connectionSocket.send(outputdata)** twice? Once inside and once outside the loop?

Comment: Where did you get the code from?  Why don't you ask the author?

Comment: Random code that you find on the internet doesn't always make sense, or do anything useful. Any idiot can post any idiot code. If you get something out of, say, the Python docs, or a reputable book or tutorial, or a highly-upvoted answer on Stack Overflow, it makes sense to ask why you don't understand it. But if it's just something you found at some random place that you have no reason to trust, the reason you don't understand it may well be that it doesn't make any sense—or, worse, it might even be malicious code that just sent someone your credit card number when you ran it.